# JQuery server side method call internal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i often call my aspx server side method with the help of jquery....like

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.aspx/Authenticate",
            data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                sHtml = data.d;
                if (sHtml != "") {
                    alert(sHtml);
                    location.href = sHtml;
                }
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }

        });
```

but the funny things is that i dont know how jquery call my static method from outside.
i saw that when i call my server side method then page_load does not fire but in case of updatepanel partial postback page_load execute first.

so i want to know the internal logic of jquery that how it can call server side method directly........looking for good explanation. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> so i want to know the internal logic of jquery that how it can call server side method directly

It can't.

jQuery can cause the browser to make an HTTP request to a URI.

The server can run code in response to a URI being requested in order to decide what content and headers to return.

Comment: u said :- jQuery can cause the browser to make an HTTP request to a URI.

The server can run code in response to a URI being requested in order to decide what content and headers to return. i wanted to how it is possible...how jquery call server side function. when we use xmlhttp then our page_load call but we can not directly call server side method...then how jquery can call a specific server side method. please guide me in detail. thanks

Comment: It **cannot** call a server side function. It can **only** cause a URI to be requested. You have to set up your webserver so that requests for that URI cause the function you want to run to be run.

Comment: u said we can not call any server side function...we can only make request...then how jquery call server side static method. in case jquery we never have to setup anything in webserver...isn't?

Comment: *u said we can not call any server side function* — Yes. *we can only make request* — Yes. *then how jquery call server side static method* — It can't and doesn't. *in case jquery we never have to setup anything in webserver...isn't?* — No.

Comment: As other people have said, when you request the URI "login.aspx/Authenticate", your server will map it onto something different to calling plain "login.aspx". This is a .NET feature, not a JavaScript or jQuery feature.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in jquery case is that the method is marked as webmethod which means that it works as an endpoint for an httprequest as if it is a webservice and when you do that, then the jquery make a httprequest to this method as if he is calling a webservice.

this URL will give you a deep view on what happen when you are making any ajax call http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx

Comment: can u give me sample javascript code by which i can call a specific server side function instead of using jquery....because if i get javascript code to make httprequest for a specific server side method then i can understand the whole thing how jquery is working. thanks

Comment: Check this link, it is the link i used to make the call to the server side method http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx

Answer (score 0):

your server side methods are marked with the [WebMethod] attribute, right? this attribute exposes the method as an xml web service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.71).aspx

since this autogenerated "webservice" has nothing to do with the page, page_load is not called.